# How can I use a Class object as a parameterized type?

Tags: java, generics

So Google turns up a lot of questions about getting the `.class` of a parameterized type, but I'm trying to go the other way.

I have a list of Classes, and I need to make a map that uses the `Class` as a key, and an `ArrayList` of objects of type Class as the value. Something like this:

```
Class[] classes = getArrayOfClasses();
HashMap<Class, ArrayList<?>> map = new HashMap<Class, ArrayList<?>>();
for(Class c : classes) {
    map.put(c, new ArrayList<c>());    // here is where the problem is
}
```

The problem of course is that it needs a parameterized type, not a class. One possible workaround is to just use `map.put(c, new ArrayList<Object>())`, but then I have to know the type and cast every object I pull.

```
MyClass myObj = (MyClass) map.get(MyClass.class).get(0);
```

I also tried making an initialization function like this:

```
private <T> ArrayList<T> makeArrayList(Class<T> c) {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

This had the syntax that I hoped would work, but it still left me with an `ArrayList` of `Object` that had to be cast.

So is there a way I can just make the `ArrayList` parameterized with the Class's type?

Comment: Use a generic method: `<T> List<T> getList(Class<T> type)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to the nature of Java's generics (they work by erasure), generics aren't available at runtime.

This means that there is no real way to make `map.put(c, new ArrayList<c>());` work.

I recommend doing this instead: Wrap your list in a dedicated object, and give that object the following accessor method:

```
public <T> getList(Class<T> key) {
    List<?> list = map.get(key);
    return (List<T>) list;
}
```

This is going to produce a warning, but as long as the map was constructed properly, you'll be ok.

Alternatively, you can do a run time check of all objects to make sure the type match up.

```
public <T> getList(Class<T> key) {
    List<?> list = map.get(key);
    for(Object o : list){
        assert(key.isInstance(o));
    }
    return (List<T>) list;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there was some way to get around the type erasure since the type was a Class, but I guess not. Wrapping the cast in a function and suppressing the warning is probably the best workaround. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no difference in the compiled bytecode between:

```
new ArrayList();
new ArrayList<T>();
new ArrayList<String>();
new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

The type parameter has no effect on the compiled code; it only affects the compiler's type-checking. So, if the type parameter is not available at compile-time, it is useless, as compile-time is the only time where it could be useful.

You should just write `new ArrayList<Object>()` or `new ArrayList<Integer>()` even `new ArrayList<CompletelyBogusUnrelatedClass>()`; it doesn't matter, because all of them are compatible with `ArrayList<?>`, which is the value type of your map.

As for your method that creates and returns an `ArrayList`, it should just be written like this:

```
private static <T> ArrayList<T> makeArrayList() {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

(That's right, this method returns an `ArrayList` of whatever element type you want *without even knowing what that type is*! This is a clear demonstration that the type parameter is not needed at runtime.)